# Style is nesting in another style asp.net view but not sure how

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In _Layout.cshtml I have the following defined in the  tag:

```
@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false);
```

The whole thing looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false);

</head>
```

Now in a view's Index.cshtml I have:

```
@section JavaScript
{
    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @@import "table/media/css/demo_page.css";
        @@import "table/media/css/demo_table.css";
    </style>
}
```

But on the line  that 'element style must not be nested in element style'.

Not sure why this is, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should use `url` with `@import`:

```
@section JavaScript
{
    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @@import url("table/media/css/demo_page.css");
        @@import url("table/media/css/demo_table.css");
    </style>
}
```

or use the `link` tag with `href`:

```
@section JavaScript
{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/table/media/css/demo_page.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/table/media/css/demo_table.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```